# Getting the three smallest values per row and returning the correspondent column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have two dataframe, df and df2,they are correspondent.
Now based in the first dataframe df, I want to get the 3 smallest value in one row and return the correspondent column's name(in this case like "X"or"Y"or"Z"or"T"). So I can get the new dataframe df3.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'X': [21, 2, 43, 44, 56, 67, 7, 38, 29, 130],
        'Y': [101, 220, 330, 140, 250, 10, 207, 320, 420, 50],
        'Z': [20, 128, 136, 144, 312, 10, 82, 63, 42, 12],
        'T': [2, 32, 4, 424, 256, 167, 27, 38, 229, 30]
    }, index=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'X': [0.5, 0.12,0.43, 0.424, 0.65,0.867,0.17,0.938,0.229,0.113],
        'Y': [0.1,2.201,0.33,0.140,0.525,0.31,0.20,0.32,0.420,0.650],
        'Z': [0.20,0.128,0.136,0.2144,0.5312,0.61,0.82,0.363,0.542,0.512],
        'T':[0.52, 0.232,0.34, 0.6424, 0.6256,0.3167,0.527,0.38,0.4229,0.73]
    },index=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
```

Besides that, I want to get another dataframe df4 which is correspondent from df3 in df2 which means in df row['A'] (2,20,21) is the 3 smallest value, so in df4 row['A'], I want to get (0.52,0.2,0.5) from df2.

Comment: What is the relationship between df and df2 and how is it involved with creating df3?

Comment: df and df2 are not related. In creating df3,  we should only use df.

Comment: Numpy solutions are approx. 10 times faster as accepted answer, check timmings in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use if both `DataFrames` has same columns names in same order [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argsort.html) for indices:

```
arr = df.values.argsort(1)[:,:3]
print (arr)
[[0 3 1]
 [1 0 3]
 [0 1 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 2 0]
 [2 3 1]
 [1 0 3]
 [0 1 3]
 [1 3 0]
 [3 0 2]]

#get values by indices in arr 
b = df2.values[np.arange(len(arr))[:,None], arr]
print (b)
[[ 0.52    0.2     0.5   ]
 [ 0.12    0.232   0.128 ]
 [ 0.34    0.43    0.136 ]
 [ 0.424   0.14    0.2144]
 [ 0.65    0.525   0.6256]
 [ 0.31    0.61    0.867 ]
 [ 0.17    0.527   0.82  ]
 [ 0.38    0.938   0.363 ]
 [ 0.229   0.542   0.4229]
 [ 0.512   0.73    0.65  ]]
```

Last use `DataFrame` constructors:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df.columns[arr])
df3.columns = ['Col{}'.format(x+1) for x in df3.columns]
print (df3)
  Col1 Col2 Col3
0    T    Z    X
1    X    T    Z
2    T    X    Z
3    X    Y    Z
4    X    Y    T
5    Y    Z    X
6    X    T    Z
7    T    X    Z
8    X    Z    T
9    Z    T    Y

df4 = pd.DataFrame(b)
df4.columns = ['Col{}'.format(x+1) for x in df4.columns]
print (df4)
    Col1   Col2    Col3
0  0.520  0.200  0.5000
1  0.120  0.232  0.1280
2  0.340  0.430  0.1360
3  0.424  0.140  0.2144
4  0.650  0.525  0.6256
5  0.310  0.610  0.8670
6  0.170  0.527  0.8200
7  0.380  0.938  0.3630
8  0.229  0.542  0.4229
9  0.512  0.730  0.6500
```

Answers are similar, so I create **timings**:

```
np.random.seed(14)
N = 1000000
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(N, 4)), columns=['X','Y','Z','T'])
#print (df1)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(N, 4), columns=['X','Y','Z','T'])
#print (df1)


def jez():
    arr = df.values.argsort(1)[:,:3]
    b = df2.values[np.arange(len(arr))[:,None], arr]
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(df.columns[arr])
    df3.columns = ['Col{}'.format(x+1) for x in df3.columns]
    df4 = pd.DataFrame(b)
    df4.columns = ['Col{}'.format(x+1) for x in df4.columns]


def pir():
    v = df.values
    a = v.argpartition(3, 1)[:, :3]
    c = df.columns.values[a]
    pd.DataFrame(c, df.index)
    d = df2.values[np.arange(len(df))[:, None], a]
    pd.DataFrame(d, df.index, [1, 2, 3]).add_prefix('Col')

def cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ():
    #another solution is wrong
    df3 = df.apply(lambda x: df.columns[np.argsort(x)], 1).iloc[:, :3]
    pd.DataFrame({'Col{}'.format(i + 1) : df2.lookup(df3.index, df3.iloc[:, i]) for i in range(df3.shape[1])}, index=df.index)


print (jez())
print (pir())
print (cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ())
```

---

```
In [176]: %timeit (jez())
1000 loops, best of 3: 412 µs per loop

In [177]: %timeit (pir())
1000 loops, best of 3: 425 µs per loop

In [178]: %timeit (cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ())
100 loops, best of 3: 3.99 ms per loop
```

Comment: The second solution is correct. The first solution doesn't include headers. They are identical.

Comment: I try it and ger errors in df4, I think only some typo, can you check it?

Comment: Yeah. the index was off. My second solution is 1.5ms.

Comment: Thank you for testing. In my opinion it is slowier because loops for df4 and the best is avoid loops in pandas.

Comment: Correct. Lookup would have been a good solution if I had known how to apply it without the loop. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.argsort` to retrieve the column names of the smallest items in each row.

```
df3 = df.apply(lambda x: df.columns[np.argsort(x)], 1).iloc[:, :3]
print(df3)

A  T  Z  X
B  X  T  Z
C  T  X  Z
D  X  Y  Z
E  X  Y  T
F  Y  Z  X
G  X  T  Z
H  T  X  Z
I  X  Z  T
J  Z  T  Y
```

An improvement to getting `df3` involves indexing `df.columns` directly (*inspired by [jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46047882/4909087)*):

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df.columns[df.values.argsort(1)].values[:, :-1], index=df.index)
df3

   0  1  2
A  T  Z  X
B  X  T  Z
C  T  X  Z
D  X  Y  Z
E  X  Y  T
F  Y  Z  X
G  X  T  Z
H  T  X  Z
I  X  Z  T
J  Z  T  Y
```

---

Using `df3`, index into `df2` using `df.lookup`.

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Col{}'.format(i + 1) : df2.lookup(df3.index, df3.iloc[:, i])\
                                        for i in range(df3.shape[1])}, index=df.index)
print(df4)

    Col1   Col2    Col3
A  0.520  0.200  0.5000
B  0.120  0.232  0.1280
C  0.340  0.430  0.1360
D  0.424  0.140  0.2144
E  0.650  0.525  0.6256
F  0.310  0.610  0.8670
G  0.170  0.527  0.8200
H  0.380  0.938  0.3630
I  0.229  0.542  0.4229
J  0.512  0.730  0.6500
```

---

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `numpy.argpartition` as it only looks to partition each row into bottom `k` and the rest.  Its time complexity is `O(n)` rather that `O(nlogn)` due to not needing to sort completely.

```
v = df.values
m = v.shape[1]

a = v.argpartition(3, 1)[:, :3]

c = df.columns.values[a]
```

We can define `df3` based on this.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(c, df.index)

df3

   0  1  2
A  T  Z  X
B  X  T  Z
C  T  X  Z
D  Y  X  Z
E  Y  X  T
F  Y  Z  X
G  X  T  Z
H  X  T  Z
I  X  Z  T
J  Z  T  Y
```

You can use this to creat `df4`

```
d = df2.values[np.arange(len(df))[:, None], a]
df4 = pd.DataFrame(d, df.index, [1, 2, 3]).add_prefix('Col')
df4

    Col1   Col2    Col3
A  0.520  0.200  0.5000
B  0.120  0.232  0.1280
C  0.340  0.430  0.1360
D  0.140  0.424  0.2144
E  0.525  0.650  0.6256
F  0.310  0.610  0.8670
G  0.170  0.527  0.8200
H  0.938  0.380  0.3630
I  0.229  0.542  0.4229
J  0.512  0.730  0.6500
```