# Determine the number of unique values between consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

I have one dataframe. I want to add one column which calculates the difference value between two adjacent rows (if the sequence is different, it doesn't matter).

For instance, if in row[A] is 12,22,5,7; in row B is 22,7,3,6 then the number is 2, etc.Because in row[a] and row[b] we have the same 22 and 7(although the sequence is different). in row b we have two new number 3,6. So we add one number in row "b" at last which records the difference between row a and row b.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [22, 7, 43, 44, 56,67,7,38,29,130],'Y': [5,3,330,140,250,10,207,320,420,50],'Z': [7,6,136,144,312,10,82,63,42,12],'T':[12, 22, 4, 424, 256,167,27,38,229,30]},index=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Can you please close your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047432/how-to-get-3-smallest-value-in-one-row-and-return-the-correspondent-columns-nam)? If one of the answers helped, please mark it accepted.

Comment: Your example is unclear, how come the expected number is 2?

Comment: Sorry. It's my fault to ask this unclear question.

Comment: I can explain my example. if in row[A] is 12,22,5,7; in row B is 22,7,3,6 then the number is 2. Because in row[a] and rwo[b] we have 22 and 7. in row b we have two new number 3,6.  So we add one number in row "b" at last which records the difference between row a and row b. Thanks.

Comment: @Hong Look at your data. It's different from what you say it is.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ   I correct this mistake. Now the dataframe df is right.

Comment: @Hong Except for F and H, all the other numbers are right in John Galt's answer?

Comment: yes. Since in row and F, they have same number in one row

Comment: So, it's 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4..... ? Correct?

Comment: yes......................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Galt in his (now, unfortunately deleted) answer was on the right track with `set` operations.

In addition, accounting for duplicates will involve:

```
s = df.apply(set, 1)
df['diffs'] = s.diff().fillna('').str.len() + (4 - s.str.len())
df

     T    X    Y    Z  diffs
A   12   22    5    7      0
B   22    7    3    6      2
C    4   43  330  136      4
D  424   44  140  144      4
E  256   56  250  312      4
F  167   67   10   10      4
G   27    7  207   82      4
H   38   38  320   63      4
I  229   29  420   42      4
J   30  130   50   12      4
```